# Does redis FLUSHALL ASYNC command block the caller?

Tags: redis

I understand that using `FLUSHALL ASYNC` will start a new thread in redis to do the cleanup. But what is the state of redis when the command returns? I want to be sure that after issuing the command, any further operations are on the freshly flushed DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does redis FLUSHALL ASYNC command block the caller?

No. The caller will return immediately.

> I want to be sure that after issuing the command, any further operations are on the freshly flushed DB

Yes, you are guaranteed that any further command will be operated on a new DB.